# White spacing in combobox elements

Tags: qt, combobox, qml

I am customizing Combobox. Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ComboBox {
    property int selectionButtonWidth: 35
    property int selectionButtonHeight: 25
    property int selectionButtonFontSize: 12
    property string mainFontFamily: "Asap"
    property color mainFontColor: "red"
    property color inputHighlight: "#9C27B0"
    property color comboboxBorderColor: "#C5C1CD"
    property int comboboxBorderWidth: 1

    id: playFromHour
    width: selectionButtonWidth
    height: selectionButtonHeight

    model: 24
    currentIndex: 1

    font.family: mainFontFamily
    font.pixelSize: selectionButtonFontSize

    property bool needHighlight: false

    onNeedHighlightChanged: {
        if (needHighlight) {
            playFromHourBack.border.color = inputHighlight
        }
        else {
            playFromHourBack.border.color = comboboxBorderColor
        }
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        id: playFromHourBack
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: comboboxBorderColor
        border.width: comboboxBorderWidth
    }

    contentItem: Text {
        text: parent.displayText
        font: parent.font
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        color: mainFontColor
    }

    indicator: Canvas {
    }

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        width: parent.width
        height: selectionButtonHeight

        contentItem: Text {
            text: modelData
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font: playFromHour.font
            color: mainFontColor
        }

        highlighted: playFromHour.highlightedIndex === index
    }

    popup: Popup {
        width: selectionButtonWidth
        height: 6 * selectionButtonHeight

        contentItem: ListView {
            clip: true
            model: playFromHour.popup.visible ? playFromHour.delegateModel : null
            currentIndex: playFromHour.highlightedIndex
        }
    }
}
```

But I face big non-customizable frame around each number. See picture attached:

[image]

I need to decrease sizes of this frame to zero, but I just don't know how to do this. Any ideas, please?

I need to fix it, so I will be able to decrease the width of the combobox. Because now with width < 40 pixels, those white frame/borders take whole space inside popup.

[image]

so there is no place for text.

Comment: provide a [mcve], Your code depends on other variables that are not defined in your example.

Comment: @eyllanesc alright, I have added variables and my imports. Do you have any ideas, how to fix this problem, please?

Comment: You could put an image of what you want to get to understand you better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to establish that the ListView occupies the same space of the parent, for that `anchors.fill : parent` is used.

```
contentItem: ListView {
    clip: true
    model: playFromHour.popup.visible ? playFromHour.delegateModel : null
    currentIndex: playFromHour.highlightedIndex
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Plus, I should add `anchors.fill: parent` to `contentItem: Text {
            text: modelData
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font: playFromHour.font
            color: mainFontColor
        }`, so horizontal center aligment will work as it should.

Comment: Maybe you also know, how I can change the color of highlight color? In screenshots above it is default grey color.